# gradle access another project

Tags: gradle, projects

I have 2 gradle projects. Lets say projectA and projectB. I need to create a task in projectA, which can execute a task in projectB. I tried with many ways, but i couldn't find a way to do that. Consider following code,

```
//ProjectA build.gradle
task taskA(dependsOn: ProjectB.taskB) << { println "executed taskB" }


//ProjectB build.gradle
task taskB() << { println "executing taskB"}
```

when I run taskA output should be,

```
>> gradle taskA
executing taskB
executed taskB
```

Can I anyhow achieve this?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
task taskA(dependsOn: project(":ProjectB").taskB)
```

We don't say that taskA executes taskB but that it *depends* on taskB.